# Change HighChart Pie based upon drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, highcharts

So I am trying to build a pie chart based upon a returned JSON object from a web socket. Once returned if the option for a "Pie Chart" has been selected then another Select drop down will be shown on to allow the user to select the time. Then the pie chart will be displayed based upon the time period However I am unable to get this option to be shown in the console. I cannot figure out how to parse the JSON to get the specific time the user has selected. I believe the problem is with the way the JSON object is constructed.

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS + Highcarts </title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='css/highChartCss.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<select id="chartType">
    <option value="line">Line</option>
    <option value="column">Column</option>
    <option value="area">Area</option>
    <option value="areaspline">Area Spline</option>
    <option value="pie">Pie(Test)</option>
</select>
    <select id="subOption"  hidden>
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="12AM-06AM">12AM-06AM</option>
        <option value="06AM-12PM">06AM-12PM</option>
        <option value="12PM-06PM">12PM-06PM</option>
        <option value="06PM-12AM">06PM-12AM</option>
    </select>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="graph">
    <section ng-app='charts'>
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
            <highchart chart='CDHLeads'></highchart>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/webSocket.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highChartAngular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function log() {
    var time = new Date();
    var formattedTime = time.toLocaleTimeString();
    var date = new Date();
    var formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString();
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = formattedDate + " " + formattedTime;
};
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#0266C8', '#0EE', '#F93', '#DDDF00', '#F90101']
});

function buildChart(title, yAxisLabel, xAxisLabels, series) {
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                type: '',
                backgroundColor: '#000000'
            },
            legend: {
                itemStyle: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    font: '12pt Inconsolata, sans-serif',
                    color: '#FFF'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: title,
                style: {
                    font: '12pt Inconsolata, sans-serif',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: xAxisLabels,
                style: {
                    font: '12pt Inconsolata, sans-serif',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {

                series: {
                    colorByPoint: false
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: yAxisLabel
                },
                tyle: {
                    font: '12pt Inconsolata, sans-serif',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            series: series
        });
        console.log(series);
    });
    $("#chartType").change(function () {
        var type = this.value;
        if (type !== "pie") {
            var cdh = $('#container').highcharts();
            document.getElementById("subOption").hidden = true;
            $(cdh.series).each(function () {
                this.update({
                    type: type,
                }, false);
            });
            cdh.redraw();
        }
        else{
            console.log("hello");
            var cdh = $('#container').highcharts();
            var time = this.value;
            console.log(time);
            document.getElementById("subOption").hidden = false;
            $(cdh.series).each(function () {
                this.update({
                    type: type
                }, false);
            });
            cdh.redraw();
        }

    });
}

var app = angular.module('charts', []);

app.directive('highchart', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="container">',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.chart, function () {

                if (!attrs.chart) return;

                var chart = scope.$eval(attrs.chart);

                angular.element(element).highcharts(chart);
            });

        }
    }
}]);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.example_chart = buildChart();
}
```

**Json Object**

```
[
  {
    "title": "Tweets",
    "y_axis_label": "Number of Tweets",
    "x_axis_labels": [
      "12AM-06AM",
      "06AM-12PM",
      "12PM-06PM",
      "06PM-12AM"
    ],
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Tweets",
        "data": [
          8,
          1,
          2,
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Retweets",
        "data": [
          8679,
          4692,
          2105,
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Replies",
        "data": [
          3427,
          789,
          1391,
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Quotes",
        "data": [
          284,
          66,
          73,
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Favorites",
        "data": [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Tweets",
    "y_axis_label": "Number of Tweets",
    "x_axis_labels": [
      "12AM-06AM",
      "06AM-12PM",
      "12PM-06PM",
      "06PM-12AM"
    ],
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Tweets",
        "data": [
          8,
          1,
          2,
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Retweets",
    "y_axis_label": "Number of Tweets",
    "x_axis_labels": [
      "12AM-06AM",
      "06AM-12PM",
      "12PM-06PM",
      "06PM-12AM"
    ],
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Retweets",
        "data": [
          8679,
          4692,
          2105,
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Replies",
    "y_axis_label": "Number of Tweets",
    "x_axis_labels": [
      "12AM-06AM",
      "06AM-12PM",
      "12PM-06PM",
      "06PM-12AM"
    ],
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Replies",
        "data": [
          3427,
          789,
          1391,
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Quoted Tweets",
    "y_axis_label": "Number of Tweets",
    "x_axis_labels": [
      "12AM-06AM",
      "06AM-12PM",
      "12PM-06PM",
      "06PM-12AM"
    ],
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Quotes",
        "data": [
          284,
          66,
          73,
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Favorites",
    "y_axis_label": "Number of Tweets",
    "x_axis_labels": [
      "12AM-06AM",
      "06AM-12PM",
      "12PM-06PM",
      "06PM-12AM"
    ],
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Favorites",
        "data": [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Angular Charts](http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/) for such case.

Comment: I am not going to rewrite everything just to use this Chart Library instead.